# returning char function data from loops

Tags: c++

I am new to the C++ language, but I would like to know how I can join my 3 loops to into a single variable to return my data for future tasks.

However I declared my variables, but I got errors.

```
char Common::punctuation(){
    char punctuation;
    for (int i = 33; i <= 47; i++)
        return (char)i;
    for (int j = 58; j <= 64; j++)
        return (char)j;
    for (int z = 91; z <= 96; z++)
        return (char)z;
    punctuation = i + j + z;
    return punctuation
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of your function? Are you trying to create a string of all punctuation characters or what? Your function currently will just always return 33, although ultimately won't compile.

Comment: I am trying to create all punctuation characters , and then return into my variable

Comment: So, really, you want to returns a string of characters. Then use a `std::string` and append to that. Or better yet, don't loop at all, just create a fixed static string containing all the characters you want to return, and return that string.

Comment: Also note that your code uses hard-coded ASCII values, which are not truly portable. And that using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) is considered bad. And that C-style casting should always be considered a red flag.

Comment: Do you consider » and « to also be punctuation, or – or even —? It's probably time to think outside of the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that the `return` statement exit the function. So everything written afterward will never be executed.
Moreover, you cannot store several characters in one `char`, you need at least an array of characters or even better a `std::string` (we are in C++).

What you wanted to do is:

```
std::string Common::punctuation()
{
    std::string result;

    for(int i = 37; i <= 47; ++i)
        result += char(i);
    for(int i = 58; i <= 64; ++i)
        result += char(i);
    for(int i = 91; i <= 96; ++i)
        result += char(i);

    return result;
}
```

Note that hard coded ascii values may be not the same in different platforms as @Some programmer dude mentioned.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are three glaring issues in your code. Firstly, your code will not compile because there are references to loop variables outside the scope of the loops.

```
for (int i = ...; i < ...; ++i) 
{
    ...
}

i    // use of undeclared identifier 'i'
```

The variable `i` exists only within the braces of the loop, which are implicit in your case. This is actually desirable since it keeps us from reusing the loop variable where it was not meant to be used. What we really want to be doing is using the loop variable to accumulate the characters we are interested in in our return variable.

This leads to the second issue in your code: we cannot accumulate anything if we return immediately. `return` marks the end of the function (barring conditional logic). So instead of returning immediately in the for loop, we should accumulate it in our return variable. Also, to improve the clarity of your code, don't give a variable the same name as any function.

Lastly, if the goal is to return all the punctuation characters, a return type of `char` won't suffice. A `char` is a single character, and what we really would like is a string of characters, so try using `std::string`.

In the end, your function might look something like:

```
#include <string>

std::string Common::punctuation(){
    std::string punct_str;
    for (char c = 33; c <= 47; ++c)
        punct_str.push_back(c);
    for (char c = 58; c <= 64; ++c)
        punct_str.push_back(c);
    for (char c = 91; c <= 96; ++c)
        punct_str.push_back(c);
    return punct_str;
}
```

or like @Some programmer dude said, just replace any call to your function by the literal that it returns, since it is not really something that needs to be computed more than once.